# How convert items li into json? (JS)

Tags: javascript, json

How convert items li:

```
<ul id='list'>
    <li>city1</li>
    <li>city2</li>
    <li>city3</li>
    <li>city4</li>
</ul>
```

'["city1","city2","city3","city4"]'

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: 1) Are you using `JavaScript` to parse that into `JSON` (or another language) ? 2) Is that `HTML` contained in a string or it actually lives in the web page (in the `DOM` precisely) ?

Comment: JavaScript!!!!!

Comment: document.quesrySelectorAll("#list li").map(li=>li.textContent).toString()

Comment: Yosi Leibman, Error: map is not a function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const list = document.getElementById("list"),
      cities = Array.from(list.children).map(each => each.innerHTML),
      citiesJSON = JSON.stringify(cities)

console.log(citiesJSON)
```

```html
<ul id='list'>
  <li>city1</li>
  <li>city2</li>
  <li>city3</li>
  <li>city4</li>
</ul>
```